# What time zone is S3Object.getObjectMetadata().getLastModified()?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to get the last modification time of a file in S3 using the ObjectMetadata method [getLastModified()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#getLastModified%28%29), as in the following snippet of code:

```
S3Object s3obj= some_s3_object;
Date someDate = s3obj.getObjectMetadata().getLastModified();
// What time zone is someDate in?
```

I'm getting back a value, but I am wondering what time zone it is in, and if I can rely on that being in the same time zone?  I can't find a reference to the time zone in the docs or anywhere else - maybe I missed it somewhere?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the method returns?

Comment: In the course of using the debugger to examine the actual date value, I discovered the fact that the Date's TimezoneOffset is actually set to PST which is the locale of the server - this is what I was hoping.  Thanks for helping me answer my own question!

Comment: You should probably answer your own question and then choose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the course of using the debugger to examine the actual date value, I discovered the fact that the Date's TimezoneOffset is actually set to PST which is the locale of the server.